# Not getting all channel list in azure media service. How to fix?

Tags: c#, azure, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I have media service and trying to get all channel list but only getting channel with 'pass through' encoding but not getting 'live encoding' type channel..below code I am using.

```
MediaServicesCredentials cred = new MediaServicesCredentials(MediaServiceName, MediaServicKey);
CloudMediaContext ctx = new CloudMediaContext(cred);
var channelList = ctx.Channels.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I got the solution of problem. I was using old **azure media service sdk 2.1.0** where only **Pass-through** type channels are get in response but all **Live** channels skipped in channel list But when I upgrade **azure media service sdk** to latest **version 3.8.0.3** It resolve this issue and get all type channel list.